# MVC: Send parameters to method by a button

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have the following button in a View

```
    <button id="Export" class="btn btn-default custom" type="button">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Export to Excel
    </button>
```

And I want it to export a list of materials that I have in a `ViewData`

I already have the logic. The code could be in a `ActionResult` or a normal method and it would be something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Export(List<int> listPassed)
    {
           //stuff here
    }
```

I tried adding `href="@Url.Action("Export", "Materials", new { export_documentation = true })"` but it didn't work out.

I could do it with an override of the `ActionLink` method but I would lose the glyphicon. Thing that I want to avoid.
Overrides of the `ActionLink` that tricks the helper to have a glyphicon also didn't work out.

I tried Ajax but I suck at jscript and ajax and all that stuff at the moment.

**Edit**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Materials",
         FormMethod.Post, new { listPassed = Request["SelectList"] }))
         {
         <button id="Export" class="btn btn-default custom" type="submit">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Export to Excel
         </button>
         }
```

This won't work out.

So, how can send the parameters to the method?

Comment: Submit the values with a form. Encode the form values using the ViewData parameters.

Comment: How do I request i.e this variable `ViewData["SelectList"] = HttpContext.Session["SelectList"] ?? new List<int>();` from a View?

Answer (score 2):

If your list is in ViewData then the object that is passed in as the 3rd parameter can be your list with the exact name that the signature of your controller specifies.

```
@Url.Action("Export", "Materials", new { listPassed= ViewData.myList })
```

Of course this will require you to use an anchor `<a href="@Url...">...</a>` instead of a button but that shouldn't be a big deal.

[Here's a link to relevant docs on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Hi @JDupont. I have a problem. `ViewData` does not have a `.myList`. I thought of something like `ViewData.Select(s => s.Value).ToArray()` but then I send an empty list.

Comment: Also, I can't nest a `<button>` element inside an `<a>` one. Can you give me some light. I don't know how to make that `<a>` element a `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your list to the ViewBag

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyView()
{
    ViewBag.SelectList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    return View();
}
```

Then from the view you submit it with a form. You'll need the *for* loop rather than a *foreach* because you need the index `i` to identify list items.

```
@{
    var list = ViewBag.SelectList as List<int>;
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("Export", "Materials", FormMethod.Post))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => list[i], new { Name="listPassed[" + i + "]" })
    }
    <button type="submit">Export to Excel</button>
}
```

Will submit to your action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Export(List<int> listPassed)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```

Comment: I'm leaving the office right now but that looks really nice. May I give you my feedback later? As soon as I get to home I will try it.